# Script Comments in RStudio not displaying in the console

Tags: r, console, comments, rstudio

I am using RStudio and recently noticed that when I use the "run" button it will not display comments in the command but just skips the line and goes to the next executable statement. I can run the entire script (with echo) and it displays the comments but any time I try and run a single line with the "run" button it will skip over comment lines. For example if I click the run button three times to execute these three lines of code:

```
4 + 4
#This is a comment
5 + 5
```

Console display:

```
>
> 4 + 4
[1] 8
> 5 + 5
[1] 10
```

This quirk just happened recently. I used the run button successfully on comments yesterday, is there a setting that might have changed or that I can change to continue to show comments on the console with the "run" button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've also noticed this evolution in the latest RStudio version (1.0.36).

Actually the run behavior has also changed in 2 other ways:

- When the cursor is anywhere in a multi-line command, clicking "Run" (or pressing <kbd>Crtl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>) now executes the **entire** command.
- When the cursor is anywhere in a comment block, clicking "Run" executes the first command below it.

To come back to the old behavior, go into:

> Tools > Global Options... > Code

and uncheck *Execute all lines in a statement*.